# Test if URL's in bookmark is offline or online in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, for-loop, bookmarks

I wonder if it is possible to test the URL's from my bookmarks.
So I can see if the URL still is online or offline.

I can see that I can test it with Urllip2
[Urllip2 code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8754)

```
import socket
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds

url = 'http://google.com/'
try :
    response = urlopen( url )
except HTTPError, e:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request. Reason:', str(e.code)
except URLError, e:
    print 'We failed to reach a server. Reason:', str(e.reason)
else :
    html = response.read()
    print 'got response!'
    # do something, turn the light on/off or whatever
```

My question is, can I get the links/URL's from my bookmarks (Chrome) and the test the URL's in a loop (for) if the URL is Offline or Online.

EDIT 26/02/2019...
Have t/ried this code, and get no folder found error..
/
    import json
    from jsonpath_rw import parse
    import os

```
# PArse te Bookmarks file from json into a dict
input_filename = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), "\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Bookmarks")
if os.path.isfile(input_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as data_file:
        bookmark_data = json.load(data_file)

# Set an xpath expression for all 'url' children
    expr = parse('$..url')

# print the value of all url keys
    print([x.value for x in expr.find(bookmark_data)])
else:
    print("File not found!")
    print(input_filename)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can read them off the machine:
"The location of the file is in your user directory then in the path `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.`"

Answer (score 0):

`Chrome` (or at least `Chromium`) stores your bookmarks in a file called `Bookmarks` in your chrome config area - on linux this is usually `.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks` on Windows it is `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks` (though you may need to hunt for it if your system is different).

Assuming you wan to check all links, then you probably want to recursively walk the tree, looking for `url` keys and getting their values. Since this is JSON, I would recommend using the `JSONPath` library (https://readthedocs.org/projects/jsonpath-rw/), rather than writing your own recursion function:

```
import json
from jsonpath_rw import parse

# PArse te Bookmarks file from json into a dict
with open('Bookmarks') as bm:
    data = json.load(bm)

# Set an xpath expression for all 'url' children
expr = parse('$..url')

# print the value of all url keys
print([x.value for x in expr.find(data)])
```

Comment: Have you printed out `input_filename` and then browsed the tree to confirm that path and filename are correct?